# Factory method returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a factory recipe to call a method from controller, here is the factory definition.

```
app.factory('AccountService', function ($http){
    var factory = {};

    factory.getAuthenticate = function (credentials) {
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/login',
            data: credentials
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config){
            return true;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config){
            return false;
        });
    }

    return factory;
});
```

When I call getAuthenticate method from one of my controller,

```
app.controller('DefaultController', function ($scope, $location, AccountService){
    $scope.login = function(){
        alert(AccountService.getAuthenticate($scope.credentials));
        // if(AccountService.getAuthenticate($scope.credentials)) {
        //     $location.path('/dashboard');
        // }
    }
});
```

It always returns undefined instead of true or false based on http calls. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: your function doesnt return anything for one, second you are doing asyc calls so your function is going to return before the ajax request is done

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: As Patrick says, an async function won't return a value like that, either return the promise or use a callback.

Answer (score -1):

$http method automatically return a promise. so you should have to handle this in a controller.your  code should be like this:

```
    app.factory('AccountService', function ($http){
        var factory = {};

        factory.getAuthenticate = function (credentials) {
            return $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/api/login',
                data: credentials
            });
        };

        return factory;
    });



app.controller('DefaultController', function ($scope, $location, AccountService){
    $scope.login = function(){
        AccountService.getAuthenticate($scope.credentials)
            .success(function (response) {
                alert('Everything went better than expected :)');
                $location.path('/dashboard');
            })
           .error(function (error) {
                alert(error);

            });
    };
});
```

Comment: Your callbacks should be abstracted out of the controller and placed into the factory. You should only do data binding inside of your controller after you made your call using the service.